# Share an array between threads in java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I'm currently working on my own little boardgame and came across a problem with multithreading. I have one thread that renders the board and one that supplies the data to render. The supply thread writes his data to one array and then the renderer takes this data and renders it on the screen (The render thread never writes something to the array). So I started to read about multithreading and shared objects and arrays between threads and the volatile keyword on arrays and found out that making an array volatile doesn't solves the problem. Then I read about happens-before relations and got a little bit confused. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility says that

> An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that monitor.

So if I understood this correct I would have to make the reads and writes to the array in a synchronized method, so in this code, the reader always has the data that the writer wrote to the array?

```
class Test {

    private static String[] data = new String[10];

    public synchronized String read(int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    public synchronized void write(String value, int index) {
        data[index] = value;
    }

    private Thread writer = new Thread(() -> {
        while(true) {
            write("Test", 0);
            System.out.println("Wrote " + read(0) + " to 0.");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                //Handle exception
            }
        }
    });

    private Thread reader = new Thread(() -> {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Read " + read(0) + " from 0.");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                //Handle exception
            }
            //Render the data
    });

    public static void main(String[] args){
        writer.start();
        reader.start();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

PS. I'm not a native speaker so please excuse some grammar mistakes.

Comment: Search the Internet for **java producer consumer** and also read the [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) lesson in Oracle's Java tutorials. Your `writer` thread is the producer and your `reader` thread is the consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AtomicReferenceArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html) will give you the semantics you are looking for. So effectively, an array with volatile elements.

In technical terms, if the read of some element in the array sees a write (of the same element), then the read will synchronize with that write. So there will be a happens-before edge between the write and the read.

Comment: Does the AtomicReferenceArray supports more dimensional arrays?

Comment: No. But you can mimic the behavior of a multi-dimensional array by converting the x,y coordinates on the chessboard into a position in the array.

Comment: Or I could create an AtomicReferencArray of AtomicReferenceArrays of Strings.

Comment: That is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), but from what you describe seems that Queue is the data structure that fits your needs the most. You have a data producer (your supplier thread) and consumer (your renderer thread). So, seems like Queue really gives you what you need. Read about the [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface, and choose the queue implementation you need, probably [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)

Comment: Good suggestions, but unfortunately they doesn't fit my needs. The CopyOnWriteArrayList doesn't works, because it has no fixed limit of elements and the problem with a Queue is, that I doesn't always access the elements in the same order and sometimes need to get info from an element twice.

Comment: As far as order goes, yes it is always provides the elements in the order they were put into the queue, that is the point of the queue. But if you need to access some element twice use ConcurrentHashMap